# Retain Persistence Volume and use the PV for new Helm install

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

In my Mongo Helm Chart, I am using PVC for Persistence volume. I am using the chart to install Mongo. When I delete the chart my PV gets deleted. So, I found something to patch it in.

```
kubectl patch pv <your-pv-name> -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

After this my PV is not getting deleted just the status in **Released**

```
pvc-fc29a491-499a-11e9-a426-42010a800ff9   8Gi        RWO            Retain           Released      default/myapp-mongodb           standard                 3d
```

How can I bound this PV to my new helm chart installation so that my data should remain persistent even after deleting my Helm Chart?

Answer (score 1):

It's still not resolved issue by Helm.

- https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/1472
- https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1933

The 'hack' to deal with it, you can find here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-sig-apps/sLL2pCJ5Ab8

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around.I have created a PVC independent of helm chart and just using it in my deployment.yaml file.
If there is existing claim just use the existing one otherwise create a new Claim.

```
 {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
      {{- if .Values.persistence.existingClaim }}
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: {{ .Values.persistence.existingClaim }}
      {{- else}}
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: {{ (include "mongodb.fullname" .) }}
      {{- end}}
```

Comment: there will be potential problem when you try to `helm upgrade install`, if the pvc is not installed by helm.

Comment: @LeiYang I have been using the existing PVC for a while now and haven't found any issue yet.Can you help me what is the issue that might come ?

Answer (score 0):

The existing PV will not be able to be bound to the new PVC.  However, the disk that your PV (`pvc-fc29a491-499a-11e9-a426-42010a800ff9`) references can be bound to your PVC.  The configuration of your new [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) will depend slightly on what cloud provider/bare metal host you are using.  I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd#pv_to_statefulset) to come to the example shown below.  This example shows how to do it with a Google Cloud GCE persistent disk.  The order matters here; make sure you create the PV (that references your existing persistent disk) before creating your PVC.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: myPV
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: myPdDiskName
    fsType: ext4
  storageClassName: standard
  claimRef:
    name: myPvcName
    namespace: myNameSpace

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myPvcName
  namespace: myNameSpace
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```